# Is it possible to use RRO without checkpoint package?

Tags: r, checkpoint, rro, microsoft-r

Revolution R Open (RRO) is distributed with `checkpoint` package to improve the reproducibility of package references. However, some users might not care about reproducibility but really cares about the performance enhancement RRO provides.

Is it possible to use RRO without `checkpoint` package and its functionality?

Comment: What do you mean? Unless you load a package, it doesn't affect you at all. Did you have a specific problem?

Comment: I mean RRO installer automatically installs checkpoint package and it alters the default way of installing and updating package to work with MRAN snapshots. What if one wants to use RRO without checkpoint package and does not want it to alter the way of package management?

Comment: They have a [forum](https://revolutionanalytics.zendesk.com/forums). You should ask there.

Comment: Package management doesn't change. Just change your default mirror to whatever you want.  Anyway, *are* you having a specific problem? Otherwise this is more appropriate for discussion at RRO's forums. SO is a Q&A site for specific programming problems, not discussion. I haven't voted to close yet, but ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to Revolution Analytics, you simply have to:

> 1. Update the .Rprofile to point to a different snapshot date: options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/YYYY-MM-DD"))
> 2. Or, set the default repository to a standard CRAN mirror that refreshes daily, for example: options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com"))

This allows you to get the most recent packages ([link](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/faq/)).